# Javascript allowing backspace and number only in input field

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have the following function which allows only number and excludes everything else when the user provides an input. However, this function is also blocking backspace and I am not being able to delete the number typed.

```js
$(function () {
  "use strict";
  var body = $("body");

  function checkKey(key) {
    if (key != 9 && (key < 48 || key > 57)) {
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }
  function goToNextInput(e) {
    var key = e.which,
      t = $(e.target),
      sib = t.next("input");

    if (key != 8 && (key < 106 && key > 96) != true && checkKey(key) == false) {
      e.preventDefault();
      return false;
    }

    if (!sib || !sib.length) {
      sib = body.find("input").eq(0);
    }
    sib.select().focus();
  }
  function onKeyDown(e) {
    var key = e.which;
    if (key != 8 && (key < 106 && key > 96) != true && checkKey(key) == false) {
      e.preventDefault();
      return false;
    }
  }

  function onFocus(e) {
    $(e.target).select();
  }

  body.on("keyup", ".otp-field", goToNextInput);
  body.on("keydown", ".otp-field", onKeyDown);
  body.on("click", ".otp-field", onFocus);
});
```

```css
input{
  width: 5rem;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" class="otp-field" maxLength="1" size="1" min="0" max="9" pattern="[0-9]{1}" name="otp[]" oninput="javascript: if (this.value.length > this.maxLength) this.value = this.value.slice(0, this.maxLength);" />
<input type="number" class="otp-field" maxLength="1" size="1" min="0" max="9" pattern="[0-9]{1}" name="otp[]" oninput="javascript: if (this.value.length > this.maxLength) this.value = this.value.slice(0, this.maxLength);" />
<input type="number" class="otp-field" maxLength="1" size="1" min="0" max="9" pattern="[0-9]{1}" name="otp[]" oninput="javascript: if (this.value.length > this.maxLength) this.value = this.value.slice(0, this.maxLength);" />
<input type="number" class="otp-field" maxLength="1" size="1" min="0" max="9" pattern="[0-9]{1}" name="otp[]" oninput="javascript: if (this.value.length > this.maxLength) this.value = this.value.slice(0, this.maxLength);" />
```

Here on line `if (key != 9 && (key < 48 || key > 57))` I tried using `key != 9 OR key != 8` as the key code for backspace is 8 but it's not working. How can I allow backspace here?

Answer (score 0):

You may achieve by adding some more.
Below I added numpad keys for exceptions.
I created another function just to check key.
First we are checking some exceptions before prevent default action.

```js
$(function () {
  "use strict";
  var body = $("body");

  function checkKey(key) {
    if (key != 9 && (key < 48 || key > 57)) {
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }
  function goToNextInput(e) {
    var key = e.which,
      t = $(e.target),
      sib = t.next("input");

    if (key != 8 && (key < 106 && key > 96) != true && checkKey(key) == false) {
      e.preventDefault();
      return false;
    }

    if (!sib || !sib.length) {
      sib = body.find("input").eq(0);
    }
    sib.select().focus();
  }
  function onKeyDown(e) {
    var key = e.which;
    if (key != 8 && (key < 106 && key > 96) != true && checkKey(key) == false) {
      e.preventDefault();
      return false;
    }
  }

  function onFocus(e) {
    $(e.target).select();
  }

  body.on("keyup", ".otp-field", goToNextInput);
  body.on("keydown", ".otp-field", onKeyDown);
  body.on("click", ".otp-field", onFocus);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="otp-field">
```

Comment: It's working but pressing backspace jumps to the next field. There are 4 fields here. Whenever a number is typed on one field it should automatically jump on the next field so the function is working perfectly here but this should not happen when backspace button is pressed. Backspace should be avoided and jumping to next field should be prevented. Can you please modify it for the same?

Comment: For the above problem I mentioned in previous comment, I have updated the question with Snippet and your code. Please have a look.